# ASP.NET web app with Javascript - properly populate database columns

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Creating a CRUD app in ASP.NET with C#, Javascript and SQL Server 2017.

The database table has three columns, `Country`, `CountryCode` and `CountryCodeId` that I'm attempting to populate with a create function (yes I'm aware of the relational design flaw here - that's outside of the scope of the question)...

I have an `enum` class that looks like this:

```
 public enum Country
    {
        [Description("Afghanistan")] AFG = 1,
        [Description("Åland Islands")] ALA = 2,
        [Description("Albania")] ALB = 3,
    }
```

I have a dropdown menu in the UI which displays the names of the country as shown in the `Description` piece above.  Let's say the chosen value of the dropdown is Afghanistan.  What I need to do upon execution of the create function is populate the `Country` column of the database with `Afghanistan`, the `CountryCode`column with `AFG` and the `CountryCodeId` column with `1`.

My Javascript skills are what are the most lacking, and I can only get the `CountryCodeId` to work, out of the three.  This is my JS code - the question marks are where I'm lost:

```
  async function newRecord(form) {
        var record = {};
        record.countryCodeId = $('#country').val();
        record.countryCode = $("???").val();
        record.country = $("???").val();
        var response = await fetch(`${endpoint}api/record`, {
            method: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(record)
        });
```

**EDIT 1**: as requested, here is the C# `Insert`function:

```
public bool Insert(Record record)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Production"));
            connection.Open();
            using (connection)
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]" +
                  "([Country]" +
                  ",[CountryCode]" +
                  ",[CountryCodeId]")
                  "VALUES " +
                  "(@Country" +
                  ",@CountryCode" +
                  ",@CountryCodeId")";
                return connection.Execute(query, record) > 0;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Controller action method for Insert:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Insert(Record record)
{
    try
    {
        bool result = _repository.Insert(record);
        return new JsonResult(new OperationResult { Success = true });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new OperationResult { Success = false, Error = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the 'Create' function ? I presume this is some controller action that's going to update the database table, yes ?

Comment: @sh1rts yes good idea.  Post edited.

Comment: missing a closing paren on your insert. Quick answer: your enum is not available in js so just submit the id and populate the rest on the server in C#

Comment: can you show your form so i know what to use as the selector

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thanks, fixed.

Comment: @LinkedListT are you referring to the HTML of the form?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: -

```
using System.ComponentModel;
.
.
void ProcessCountry(string countryCode)
{
    Country country;

    // i.e. countryCode = "AFG"
    if (Enum.TryParse(countryCode, out country))
    {
        string description = null; 

        try
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = country.GetType().GetField(country.ToString());
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = 
               (DescriptionAttribute[])
                   fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            description = ((attributes.Length != 0) ? 
                                attributes[0].Description : 
                                country.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
            {
                description = "Unknown";
            }
        }

        int value = Convert.ToInt32(country);
        Console.Write($"countryCode: {countryCode}, description: {description}, value: {value}");
    }
}
```

The FieldInfo/DescriptionAttribute stuff pulls the description out of the System.ComponentModel.Description attribute, and as you've given your enum values INT values then you can parse them as Int.

Comment: Thanks for this code @sh1rts.  As far as putting this into context with my project, where and when would I call the `ProcessCountry` method?

Comment: It's an example only - reuse what you need. Can you post the controller action method your JavaScript is calling ? (not the method that inserts data)

Comment: See Edit 2 - is that what you're referring to?